# Vertical centering view, autoresizing and iPhone 5 4" screen

Tags: ios, uikit, xib, iphone-5, autoresizingmask

I have some custom buttons I add to the view in `-viewDidLoad`. I want them centered vertically inside the view, like so:

```
self.customButton.center = CGPointMake(98.f, self.view.center.y);
```

However, the view height is `504.0` even on a 3.5" device, where I expect it to be `416` (480 - 20 (status bar height) - 44 (nav bar height)).

The view in xib is using "Retina 4 Fullscreen", but setting it to freeform does not help. I certainly don't want two xibs just to account for the height difference.

I know I can use UIScreen but I would prefer that the view be aware of the height difference.

EDIT: the odd thing is, in `-viewWillAppear`, view height is correctly set to `416.0`. Why this isn't handled after `[super viewDidLoad]` is beyond me.

How are people handling this? Autolayout would probably handle this but I need a iOS5 compatible method. Can autoresizing handle "centering" somehow?

Comment: There is a layout constraint called center vertically in view. You might want to try that.

Comment: I believe you are referring to autolayout which is iOS6+

Comment: Sorry, misread that last sentence!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have Autolayout in iOS5, but you do still have the autoresizing mask. If you center a view vertically in IB, go to the inspector and deselect the vertical struts and springs in the autolayout masks, the view will stay centered vertically on both 4" and 3.5" screens.

Or you can do this in code in your viewDidLoad method. Just center the view as you are now and set the autoresizingMask like this:

```
 self.customButton.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | \
                                       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin);
```

Answer (score 1):

> EDIT: the odd thing is, in `-viewWillAppear`, view height is correctly set to 416.0. Why this isn't handled after `[super viewDidLoad]` is beyond me.

Because resizing the view is not part of loading the view! `-viewDidLoad` gets called from `-view` in a method that probably looks a bit like this:

```
-(UIView*)view
{
  if (!_view)
  {
    [self loadView];
    [self viewDidLoad];
  }
  return _view;
}

-(void)loadView
{
  // Some code to load the view from a nib/storyboard...
}
```

The view will get resized with a call like `yourViewController.view.frame = ...`, but this can only happen *after* the view is loaded (and thus after `-viewDidLoad` is called).

Set some autoresizing masks. That's what they're there for.